# in netbeans 6.8 how do you insert an image and change the size of it?

Tags: java, netbeans

in netbeans 6.8 how do you insert an image and change the size of it?
i have tried to insert an image into a label. this allows me to change the size of the label but not the size of the image.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the [`getScaledInstance()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,%20int,%20int)) method of class [`Image`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance(int,%20int,%20int)).

Comment: See also this [alternative approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6916719/230513), which links to helpful article.