# Java - screen layout messes up when image displayed

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager

I have a several buttons running vertically on a panel and then 3 panels to their right.  Each will display a picture depending on input from the buttons.

The problem I have is that as an image gets displayed it increases the size of the buttons and I would like them to stay are they are.

How do I prevent the resizing to occur?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Can you [scale](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6916719/230513) the images to a common size?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). It gives you a lot of freedom and if you're using [Netbeans Form Building tool](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-functionality.html) it's really easy to create good looking GUIs.

Comment: Netbeans will build the code for you. I don't know if that's what you mean, but if that is the case you can write the code yourself... It's really a great solution. I use grid bag for (almost) everything. You get a lot more control.

Comment: I'm not a `GridBagLayout` fan, but the NetBeans designer is a _great_ way to experiment: change something, check the code, change, check, etc. You can always throw away the `.form` and keep the code.