# How to resize Image Icon on Menu Item

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JMenuItem ImageIcon too big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916693/jmenuitem-imageicon-too-big)

The size of Icon to large can it decrase.
See below link.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2PXtUeqJPCpQWFLcGQ0NTg2UVU/edit

How do i set the size of icon on MenuItem without resize with raw file pls:thanks.

Comment: Post your code in question

Answer (score 3):

`Image` has the method `public Image getScaledInstance(int width, int height, int hints)` you can use to resize your menu icon.

Comment: +1 for convenience; see this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6916693/230513) for caveats.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could do it some other way, but this might be worth a try - an AWT idea; resize the image before setting it as the menu item icon:

```
// myIcon is your image icon
imageToolkit = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit;
iconImage = imageToolkit.createImage(myIcon);
iconImage = iconImage.getScaledInstance(32,32,iconImage.SCALE_SMOOTH);
// set this icon for the menu
```