# Can I make resizable the icon inside a jlabel?

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, imageicon

Is there any property or any code that I can implement to make an icon inside a `JLabel` resizable. Or is there any other item which can store an image, that I could use to have a resizable image inside a `JFrame`?

Comment: What you mean by resizable? if you resize your jlabel then the icon could resize too

Comment: I'm using netbeans, and when I try to resize the jlabel i cant, the size of the image inside just stays fixed while the jlabel is being resized (which cuts parts of the image).

Comment: Short answer: You will have to make something yourself or find a library that does it for you. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
 photo = new ImageIcon(UrlofPhoto); 
 Image im = photo.getImage();
 Image Newim = im.getScaledInstance(yourlabel.getWidth(),  yourlabel.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
 ImageIcon Newphoto=new ImageIcon(Newim);
 yourlabel.setIcon(Newphoto);
```

don't forget to set an initialised size to yourlabel

Comment: Take a look at [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) for reasons why this is not always a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would't suggest trying this with a `JLabel` as `JLabel` has a lot of other features you really don't want to messing with (alignment and text).

Generally, a better solution is to use a dedicated "image" panel, which you can provide additional control over to fine tune how you want the scaling to work.

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003)

If you're really stuck on using `JLabel`, I would recommend attaching a `ComponentListener` to it and resizing the underlying image when ever it changes size.  The problem with this is `componentResized` may be called repeatedly in quick succession, meaning you will need to devise some kind of coalescing algorithm that only reacts to the last event within a given period of time...

Answer (score 0):

Check out Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) which will dynamically scale the icon to fill the label.