# Image background on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

How can I make my image background bigger to fill up the space of the JFrame.

```
private static void gamePanel() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mascot Fight Game");
    frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(System
            .getProperty("user.dir") + "/image/big10_legends_leaders.gif")));
    Container panel = frame.getContentPane();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    String[] iconString = new String[3];
    int[] boundInt = new int[3];
```

Comment: make your image bigger

Comment: @FastSnail That's hardly a solution.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14548808/369450

Comment: You will want to learn how to [search this site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+jframe+background+image), for surely a similar question has been asked many times before.