# Error in building simple window?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, compiler-errors

I am trying to build a window with one picture that covers up the screen. The picture is a JLabel and the window is a JFrame. After trying countless ways and looking up multiple tutorials for hours, I have not figured out how to do this. I agree, this is a very simple question, but I simply do not understand how I can approach this problem. Here is my code I have tried(I commented out some things that I tried earlier):

```
package Buttons;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

 public class Mewindow extends JFrame {

private JFrame mewindow;
private JLabel mepic = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("me.png"));

public Mewindow() {

    super("Here is a picture of ME!");

    mewindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

    // Icon me = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("me.png"));

    add(mepic);

    mewindow.setVisible(true);
    mewindow.setSize(250, 250);
    mewindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}

}
```

Thank you so much for the time you are taking for reading this, I really appreciate the effort you are putting into helping a fellow programmer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem #1...

You have no main method, so unless you're creating the class from another class, it won't run...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            Mewindow frame = new Mewindow();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

## Problem #2...

Now, you will run into a `NullPointerException`, because `mewindow` is not initialised, but, you don't actually need it, because you're using the values within the constructor of the class, so you would end up with a `StackOverflowException` if you tried to intiialise it ... but it doesn't make sense to use it anyway...

```
public class Mewindow extends JFrame {

    private JLabel mepic
    public Mewindow() {

        super("Here is a picture of ME!");

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

        mepic = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("me.png")));
        add(mepic);

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(250, 250);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Now your code assumes that `me.png` is stored within the same package as the `Mewindow`, just beware of that.

And, the resulting code actually running (replace with my own picture)

[image: MeWindow]

## Suggestions...

Don't extend directly from `JFrame`, use a `JPanel` instead and then add that to an instance of `JFrame`, your code will be more re-usable

Comment: Thank you, this was very well explained. I guess I should have directly put the image into a JLabel itself! What do you mean "Don't extend directly from JFrame, use a JPanel instead and then add that to an instance of JFrame, your code will be more re-usable" ? Also, my image isn't filling up the whole window, why is that? It may be the image itself though...?

Comment: It's generally discouraged to extend from a top level container as it will lock you into a single use case, and you're not really adding any new functionality to the class.  It also comes with a bunch of other management issues which are best left to the implementation.  `JLabel` doesn't scale the image, ever, in fact, no Swing component does, instead, you need to implement the functionality yourself

Comment: Have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)